# 1080p @ 60fps for the iMX 6 Quad or iMX 8?

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, imx6

I am attempting to do video encoding and streaming simultaneously on the iMX 6 Quad. Currently, this is the pipeline that I am using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc num-buffers=300 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1280,height=720,framerate=60/1! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! \
   tee name=t \
   t. ! queue ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location="test-3.mp4" \
   t. ! queue ! imxipuvideosink
```

Note that the videotestsrc is to simulate a camera that has a YUY2 output format.

I can't go beyond 720p @ 60fps [this includes any frame-rate for 1080p as well]. Is this a performance bottleneck due to the hardware or the pipeline that I have setup? Because I am getting warning messages like this:

```
   WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstImxIpuVideoSink:imxipuvideosink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
   Additional debug info:
   gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstImxIpuVideoSink:imxipuvideosink0:
   There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Also, if anyone has an iMX 8 board, could you attempt to run 1080p @ 60fps and see whether this pipeline has any performance issues?

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc num-buffers=300 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=60/1! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! \
   tee name=t \
   t. ! queue ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location="test-3.mp4" \
   t. ! queue ! imxipuvideosink
```

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bottlenecks in your pipeline:

1. First of all, having videotestsrc generate a 1080 stream is way too much. I recommend using a camera if possible or, at least, changing the `pattern` property to `black`.
2. Don't use `videoconvert`, that is software based. In the imx6 you may use `imxipuvideotransform` or `imxg2dvideotransform` which are HW based.